# SQL Server matching data subsets

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table history_data

```
timestamp, data  
2006-07-07 07:17:00.000,1  
2006-07-07 07:18:00.000,2  
2006-07-07 07:19:00.000,3  
2006-07-07 07:20:00.000,**4**  
2006-07-07 07:21:00.000,**5**  
2006-07-07 07:22:00.000,**6**  
2006-07-07 07:23:00.000,7  
2006-07-07 07:24:00.000,8  
2006-07-07 07:25:00.000,9  
2006-07-07 07:26:00.000,**4**  
2006-07-07 07:27:00.000,**5**  
2006-07-07 07:28:00.000,**6**  
2006-07-07 07:29:00.000,3  
2006-07-07 07:30:00.000,6  
2006-07-07 07:31:00.000,2
```

I have another table temp_records

```
records  
4  
5  
6
```

Expected Result

start_match, end_match
2006-07-07 07:20:00.000, 2006-07-07 07:22:00.000
2006-07-07 07:26:00.000, 2006-07-07 07:28:00.000

How do I return the period (start_match, end_match) for the period matching the subset in temp_records. That is, the consecutive rows that match in that particular order.

This is a simplified definition of the problem. The real life example has 4+ million rows in the history_data table and <100 rows in the temp_records table so i'm hoping I can find an efficient solution to pattern match the subset in the main set.

**EDIT**

I apologize if I have not been clear in my request. I'm not the type to continue arguing, it is just a waste of energy from both parties. What I am looking for is the SQL Server equivalent of this http://www.pythian.com/blog/sql-for-pattern-matching-in-oracle-12c/. I am looking for a method to match a sequence of rows spanning a period.

Comment: post the sql to create this table and insert sample rows.

Comment: why don't you post an example of the output that you expect ? until then, you get a -1.

Comment: I've simplified this problem immensely so as to not have to go through and explain the real life scenario. If you read the question again a little more carefully you would notice that I asked for the period (start_match, end_match). Two columns noting the start and end date of each match made. You get a -1 for paying attention.

Comment: What do you mean by start and end ? Consecutive start and end for each id or just the first date and last date for each id. If you don't even know how to mention it clearly, then how will others understand.

Comment: okay, why don't you tell us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: For any match made between the subset and the main set, I would like the dates compromising the start and end date of that match. In the above scenario this would return (2006-07-07 07:20:00.000, 2006-07-07 07:22:00.000) as one records and (2006-07-07 07:26:00.000, 2006-07-07 07:28:00.000) as another records.

Comment: then add that information to your question. btw, did you try to solve this yourself. If yes, show us that query.

Comment: If i knew how to solve it with a query I wouldn't be asking. I'm solving it at the moment through C# code which is too slow and memory intensive because i need to hold the entire working set in memory as I iterate through it and look for a subset match. For this reason, as an alternative i'm attempting to do it at the database level. I don't want or need the exact query if it can be done that way. It will suffice for someone to simply explain to me the most efficient method of doing it and what to use from which I can take it from there.

Comment: so, you have not tried to make any sql and you want us to do your homework for you ?

Comment: You clearly have no idea how to solve the problem, go away.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use the below query to achieve your result.

```
SELECT MAX(a.RECORDS) as RECORDS,b.StartTime,a.EndTime
FROM
(select t2.RECORDS,MAX(TIMESTAMP) EndTime from Table1 t1 join Table2 t2
on t1.[data] like '%'+CAST(t2.RECORDS as varchar(10))+'%'
GROUP BY t2.RECORDS) a
JOIN 
(select t2.RECORDS,MIN(TIMESTAMP) StartTime from Table1 t1 join Table2 t2
on t1.[data] like '%'+CAST(t2.RECORDS as varchar(10))+'%'
GROUP BY t2.RECORDS) b
ON a.RECORDS=b.RECORDS
GROUP BY a.RECORDS,b.StartTime,a.EndTime
```

Also look at the [FIDDLE LINK FOR FULL QUERY WITH RESULTS](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c397/14)

Comment: Thanks for your attempt but it was not quite what I had in mind. I want to return 1 row with a start and end time for each occurrence of the pattern {4,5,6}.

Comment: @user1891085 - So we have to keep guessing what is REALLY in your mind ? Let me gaze into my crystal ball and see what you want.

Comment: @Anand - The data column should be an int. Then, you can get the same output with a much simpler query - `select hd.data, 
MIN(hd.timestamp) as startdt, 
MAX(hd.timestamp) as enddt
from table2 as tr
left join table1 as hd
on tr.records = hd.data
group by hd.data
order by hd.data asc` BUT, that is not what the OP wanted. So, enjoy the guessing game.

Comment: @ Borat Sagdiyev -- Yeah if its int thn performance will also be much better. OP's table structure also not optimized.